# magento 1.9 special offer timer for first time user

Tags: magento-1.9, php, coupon, offers

For my  Magento 1.9 website, I want to set the **special offer timer**. In which I want to display this timer to **first time user (new visitor) only** and it will use this offer within an hour only. After an hour this offer will be expired for the customer.

[image]

Can anyone let me know how to handle/add this type of timer and coupons in Magneto backend and setting up in Magneto front-end.